# iOS - handle global app variables from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a couple of objects stored in the user's NSUserDefaults which I have to use more or less in every single ViewController of my app.

Currently, I basically have the same 3 variables declared, and in the viewDidLoad I initialise them like:

```
if(....){
     chosenID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"chosen_xxxx"] integerValue];
     chosenName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"chosen_name"];
}else{
     chosenID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"chosen_xxxx_2nd option"] integerValue];
     ...
}
```

I'm looking to clean up my code and optimize my code, and I was wondering what the right way to handle a case such like this was, to avoid having these 10-12 exact same lines of code at the start of every single ViewController.

Comment: As always, **never use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC**. `NSUserDefaults` has dedicated methods `stringForKey`, `integerForKey`, `objectForKey.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an utility class. And create some class methods.

One method can be like,

```
+ (NSString *)choosenName {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"chosen_name"];
}
```

And call the method like,

```
chosenName = [Your_Utility_Class choosenName];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve it globally by following simple method.Create NSObject class,please refer my example below.

**.h File**

```
 //Setting up Session
  +(void)SetEmail:(NSString*)value;
  +(void)SetFirstName:(NSString*)value;

 //Retrieve
  +(NSString*)GetEmail;
  +(NSString*)GetFirstName;
```

**.m file**

```
 +(void)SetEmail:(NSString *)value{

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"EMAILID"];
    }

    +(void)SetFirstName:(NSString *)value{

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"FIRSTNAME"];

    }

 +(NSString*)GetEmail{
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"EMAILID"];
    }

    +(NSString*)GetFirstName{
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"FIRSTNAME"];
    }
```

Now Move to Viewcontroller and access without alloc init as it is in Class method.I am setting up from result.

**Setting up in Viewcontroller**

```
[NSDefaultSession SetEmail:@"YourString"];
[NSDefaultSession SetFirstName:@"YourString"];
```

**Now Getting Session from any ViewController**

```
[NSDefaultSession GetEmail]
[NSDefaultSession GetFirstName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should put these values into an object, and secondly use dependency injection.

So first make a class `Chosen` (for want of a better name) and give it the properties `id` and `name`. Now the only thing that needs to worry about where the data is saved and loaded from is the 'Chosen' object, everything else will go through that.

Ok now the dependency injection. You want your VC dependencies to be obvious and clear, don't rely in singletons like NSUserDefaults hidden away inside them. So make .chosen a public property on each of the VC's that needs access to the object.

Init this object in `application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and now inject that into your initial viewController. (ie, set the public property)

Now just pass along the object again by injection to each of the other viewController that needs access to it.

Answer (score 0):

in my option:

create commonClass (sub class of NSObject class)

crate spare methods  and use them where u need.

ex:

**in ur vc1:**

set the values for ur objects

```
chosenID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"chosen_xxxx"] integerValue];
     chosenName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"chosen_name"];
```

**in ur common class:**

```
+(NSString *) chosenID{
    NSUserDefaults *serverDefults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * chosenID =[serverDefults objectForKey:@"chosen_xxxx"];
    if (chosenID.length==0) {
              // do some actions 
            }
    return chosenID;
}
```

**in another VC2:**

```
 NSString *id =[commonClass chosenID];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the ***right*** way to address this issue. Common functionality is what sub-classing is all about - your view controllers are a specific type of view controller that needs access to these variables.

- Create class BaseViewController, which is a sub-class of a UIViewController.
- Give BaseViewController two public properties called chosenId and chosenName.
- Add the init code you have to the viewDidLoad of BaseViewController.
- Remove the init code from each of your existing view controllers.
- Make any view controller that requires these variables of type BaseViewController intead of UIViewController.

Those variables are now magically (and consistently) available in all of your view controllers without ***any*** code duplication.